# Class Operations

Tags: c++, class, exception, throw

I am a little hung on on completing this program

The assessment asks us Following the information provided below, implement a RockConcert and TicketHolder class. The class TicketHolder represents someone who paid for admission a particular concert. This TicketHolder class should keep track of the what it cost and where the seat located.

I have constructed most of the code, given the Driver that was provided, but I am pretty stumped with how to go about coding methods RockConcert::sellTicket and, RockConcert::getTicket

Below is the code,

Thanks a ton!

**TicketHolder.h**

```
#ifndef TicketHolder_h
#define TicketHolder_h
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TicketHolder {

public:
    TicketHolder();
    TicketHolder( std::string seat, double cost );

    std::string getSeat() const;
    double getCost() const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const TicketHolder & t);

private:
    std::string my_Seat;
    double my_Cost;
};

#endif
```

**TicketHolder.cpp**

```
#include "TicketHolder.h"


TicketHolder::TicketHolder(){

}
TicketHolder::TicketHolder( std::string seat, double cost ){
    my_Seat = seat;
    my_Cost = cost;
}

std::string TicketHolder::getSeat() const{
    return (my_Seat);
}

double TicketHolder::getCost() const{
    return (my_Cost);

}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const TicketHolder & t){
    return os;
}
```

**RockConcert.h**

```
#ifndef RockConcert_h
#define RockConcert_h
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "TicketHolder.h"
#include "SeatAlreadySold.h"
#include "SeatNotFound.h"

class RockConcert {

public:
    public:
    RockConcert( std::string date, std::string location );

    void sellTicket( std::string seat, double cost ) throw (SeatAlreadySold);
    TicketHolder getTicket( std::string seat ) throw (SeatNotFound);
    double getProceeds( );

    friend std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& out, const RockConcert & r );


private:
        TicketHolder myTickets[ 20 ];
        int myNumberOfTicketsSeenSoFar;
        std::string my_When;
        std::string my_Where;

    };

#endif
```

**RockConcert.cpp**

```
    #include "RockConcert.h"
    #include "TicketHolder.h"

    RockConcert::RockConcert( std::string date, std::string location ) {
        my_When = date;
        my_Where = location;
    }

    void RockConcert::sellTicket( std::string seat, double cost ) throw (SeatAlreadySold){

    }

    TicketHolder RockConcert::getTicket( std::string seat ) throw(SeatNotFound) {


    }

    double RockConcert::getProceeds( ){
        return (myNumberOfTicketsSeenSoFar);

    }

    std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& out, const RockConcert & r ){
        return out;
    }
```

**Driver.CPP**

```
// driver
// function main
#include "TicketHolder.h"
#include "RockConcert.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

{
RockConcert megaDeath( "Sept 1", "Staples Center" );
megaDeath.sellTicket( "Row Q Seat 20", 120.00 );
megaDeath.sellTicket( "Row Q Seat 21", 120.00 );
megaDeath.sellTicket( "Row SSS Seat 12", 50.00 );
TicketHolder ticket = megaDeath.getTicket( "Row Q Seat 21" );

// Print out the concert and its tickets
std::cout << megaDeath << std::endl;


try {


    megaDeath.sellTicket( "Row T Seat 30", 65.00 );

} catch( SeatAlreadySold sas ) {

    std::cout << "An error occurred here for the reason:";
    std::cout << sas.what(std::endl:endl;
}

// Print out the library and its book - notice the difference
std::cout << megaDeath << std::endl;
// Let's try to throw some errors...
try {
    // can't sell a ticket that has already been sold
    megaDeath.sellTicket( "Row Q Seat 21", 120.00 );
    std::cout << "An error occurred here..." ;
} catch( SeatAlreadySold sas ) {
    sas.what();
}

try {
    // can't get a ticket that has not been sold
    megaDeath.getTicket( "Row A Seat 1" );
    std::cout << "An error occurred here..." ;
} catch( SeatNotFound snf ) {
    snf.what();
}

}
```

Comment: So, what is the **question**?

Comment: @soon "I am pretty stumped with how to go about coding methods RockConcert::sellTicket and, RockConcert::getTicket"

Comment: @brorez that's not a question, that's a statement. What have you tried and why didn't that work? We're not here to do your homework for you, doubly so last thing on Sunday evening.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the question is here, but I would be inclined to create a `std::map` mapping a ticket ID (which could jsut be a string like "Row ## Seat ##", as long as you're consistent) to a `TicketHolder` instance. Your `TicketHolder` class (which I think would be better named just `Ticket`) should include a boolean "sold" property.

In your `getTicket()` method, a simple lookup in the `std::map` would be fine, and very fast.

Your `sellTicket()` method should first call `getTicket()`, then check the "sold" property of the returned ticket (throwing an exception if it's already sold). If not, then set `TicketHolder::sold = true`. You should also add the ticket cost to a running total of the proceeds so far.

Other general rules that might be useful:

- Use initialisation lists in constructors when you can
- Avoid exception specifiers in C++, they probably don't do what you think
- Unless you really know what you're doing, always throw exceptions by value, and catch by const reference.
- Avoid copying `std::string`s and other complex objects in your function arguments
- Likewise, think carefully about when your method return types should be copies, when they should be references, when they should be const references, and when they should be (smart) pointers.